# How can I get the actual result of a Stored Procedure using .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, .net-core

Just ramping up on .NET Core and running into some unsolvable problems.
I have a stored procedure called GetLeads whose schema basically returns

```
LEADID (INT)
SALENO (INT)
OFFICE (INT)
PACKAGE (NVARCHAR(4)
SALEDATE (DATETIME)
```

For sake of an example, there is a table in the same database where that Stored Procedure resides called Prospects. Its schema is

```
LEADID (INT)
FNAME (NVARCHAR(50))
LNAME (NVARCHAR(50))
ADDR1 (NVARCHAR(150))
ADDR2 (NVARCHAR(150))
EMAIL (NVARCHAR(200))
PHONENO (NVARCHAR(200))
CONTACTDATE (DATETIME)
```

According to the docs, I can use the FromSql method of a context model to call a stored procedure. But what if the stored procedure returns a schema having a only a few (if any) of the fields that match the model of the context from which the call is made?

If I construct a Query such as:

```
var _ctx = new DbContext();
var pkgs = _ctx.Prospects.FromSql("EXEC dbo.GetPackages").ToList();
```

This obviously will fail due the fact that returned recordset doesn't contain fields relevant to the Prospects model.

Conversely, using something like:

```
var pkgs = _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.GetPackages");
```

Is pointless as well because it will only return the number of records affected by the command execution.

So the FromSql method available in .NET Core obviously has its set of limitations although it's documented as available for making stored procedure calls.

Ideally, I'd like to see the Core Framework have the ability to make direct calls to Stored Procedures and Functions in much the same manner as is with EF within the .NET Framework and simplify things. But I realize that functionality isn't yet available in Core; though I hope it eventually does.

Anyway, enough rambling and to the point.

How or what currently is the most practical and widely accepted way to call a stored procedure under these set of circumstances in .NET Core? I know ADO.NET is an option but I'm speaking strictly within the paradigm of the Core Framework using EF

Comment: Use ExecuteNonQuery with the cmd set to :  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: what about `_ctx.Database.SqlQuery<YourModelThatFitsYourProcedureOutput>()` ?

Comment: @Selvin per EF DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for SqlQuery

Comment: oh ... so what about `_ctx.Query<YourModelThatFitsYourProcedureOutput>().FromSql()`

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbQuery.

Comment: @Mark Have you tried using the Snickler.EFCore package which provides fluent Methods for mapping Stored Procedure results to objects in EntityFrameworkCore: https://github.com/snickler/EFCore-FluentStoredProcedure

Comment: Please read about Query Types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm going to give some credit to Selvin for his last comment as it did prompt me down the path for a solution. But I really needed an explicit answer.
I'm going to also acknowledge the much appreciated comment from Rahul for using Snickler as an alternative. But I wanted a solution that solely involved nothing more than EF and .NET Core. Quite honestly, all the comments are greatly appreciated*

So here are the actual steps required to always be able to get the **FromSql** method to work with Stored Procedures within the Entity Framework. I am using the Database First approach using MVC but the overall methodology for the solution shouldn't matter.

Note: If the EF context has already been created, Step 1 can be skipped.

**Step 1:** Generate the EntityFramework context and associated Entity Models from the database using the dotnet utility.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=[YourDBServerName];Initial Catalog=[YourDatabaseName];Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[YourUserId];Password=[YourUserPassword];" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

**Step 2:** Add a ViewModel that defines all the fields that your stored procedure will return. Note: You could alternately add this as a Model instead, but I prefer to keep the stored procedure entities distinctly separated from the Models generated directly from the database for brevity and a clear separation of the architecture.

Equally important, the entity class MUST have a primary key or it won't work. EF requires that all entities have a primary key.

```
public partial class Lead
{
    [Key]
    public int leadid { get; set; }
    public int saleno { get; set; }
    public int office { get; set; }
    public string package { get; set; }
    public datetime saledate { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 3:** Add the stored procedure entity Model created in Step 2 to the Database context as a virtual DbSet. This should be located in the Models directory created by Step 1 and would have the word "Context" prepended in the name.

```
public virtual DbSet<Lead> Lead { get; set; }
```

After performing these steps 2 and 3 you can all any stored procedure using the FromSql method within the Core Framework

```
var _ctx = new DbContext();
var pkgs = _ctx.Prospects.FromSql("EXEC dbo.GetPackages").ToList();
```

Note: Since record sets returned from stored procedures don't require the presence of a primary key you could either:

1. Modify the Stored Procedure to include a Primary Key such as an identity field
2. Identify a couple of fields within the returned record set that would constitute as being viable primary keys and create a composite key within the Model

However the 2nd option requires some additional work and considerations because you'll have to use fluent API to set composite primary keys. EF Core won't allow Data Annotations to set composite keys.

Hopefully this shared information will help others who journey the same path with the similar question